# WPF form should resize to show its content

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When WPF window appear first time, its content seem frozen. To refresh content I need to resize form, then it will be fixed. Or I hit the TAB then find a listbox -it's not visible- and click it and viola! Form updates its content again.

What do you think? Weird huh? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Edit:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Show();

   while (!AppMain.needClose)
   {
      System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
      DoThings();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing the window would force the internals to invalidate and re-paint. You could try invalidating the form when it's loaded to force it to do the same:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Show();

   this.Invalidate();

   while (!AppMain.needClose)
   {
      System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
      DoThings();
   }
}
```

Unless you're doing some sort of custom message pumping though, the standard forms message pump should do that while loop for you. You might well find that because you're intercepting the window loaded event you're stopping initialisation from completing.

Calling DoEvents is a bad code smell in my experience. If you need to do something periodically, it's better to trigger it from a timer of some sort.

Comment: Invalidate() is invalid in WPF.

Comment: Try removing all that code from the `window_loaded` method then. What does `DoThings();` do ?

Comment: I removed the loop part, it has no problem now. What's the best method, should I use one shot timer?

Comment: That very much depends on what are you trying to trigger?

Answer (score 1):

When your window is loaded it's already shown, why are you calling this.show() again??

Comment: I just ported from windows form to WPF. I removed the line.